# Importing .fbx Character in Blender

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender, blender-2.61

I am new in blender. I have learned some basic function of blender .How to make simple shapes and how to animate. Now I have a character in .fbx formate but it has no animation.I want to animate it in Blender so that I can use it in Unity... but I don't know how to import .fbx file in Blender. Any idea or suggestion?

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Comment: I don't think that this should have been closed as "not a real question". I personally think that this question is obvious; Ben is asking how to import .fbx files into Blender...no?

Answer (score 2):

If the .fbx option does not appear in Blender you probably need to enable the importer. 
Go to **File > User Preferences > Import-Export** and enable (right-most tick) **Import-Export: Autodesk FBX format**

[image: Blender Autodesk FBX Import-Export enable]

Comment: I got Blender 2.60a for Mac. I enabled the above plugin but the Autodesk FBX format does not appear in **File > Import** (however, it appears in **File > Export**)

Comment: I haven't used Belnder 2.60a yet. Perhaps the FBX importer is missing ? You could try a slightly older version of Blender. A more cumbersome  that could not work is copying the fbx io scripts from an older (2.5x) version of Blender into 2.60 but it's not guaranteed to work. Try using a version of Blender 2.5x for now